# entity framework doesn't update table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update my table. It changes and back to server but it doesn't update my table. If i edit on  employeeInformation.APersonal.Name and show on contoller with edited name. But in database table doesn't change. remain with existing value. Please help me.

```
   public class EmployeeInformation()
    {
    public Guid Id{set;get;)
    public int TrainingHistoryId{set;get;}
    public virtual TrainingHistory ATrainingHistory { set; get; }

    }

    public class TrainingHistory ()
    {
    public int id{set;get;)
    public string TrainingName{set;get;}
    public virtual IList<Training> Trainings{set;get;}
    public virtual IList<ProfessionalTraining> ProfessionalTrainings{set;get;}
    }
    public class ProfessionalTrainings()
    {
    public int Id{set;get;)
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public double Grade{set;get;}
    public string institute{set;get;}
    public virtual IList<TrainingHistory > TrainingHistories{set;get;}
    }
    public class Trainings()
    {
    public int id{set;get;}
     public string name{set;get;}
    public string PassingYear{set;get;}
     public virtual IList<TrainingHistory > TrainingHistories{set;get;}
}
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EmployeeEdit(EmployeeInformation employeeInformation)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        var path = "";
                        if (employeeInformation.AFile.Picture!=null&&employeeInformation.AFile.Picture.ContentLength !=0)
                        {

                            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Employee"), employeeInformation.AFile.FilePathCode + ".jpg");
                            employeeInformation.AFile.Picture.SaveAs(path);

                        }
                        var a=db.
                        db.Entry(employeeInformation).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList");
                    }
                    return View(employeeInformation);
                }
```

In controller employee information has all of the  required value and modified value. but its not update the value.

Comment: you have set the entity state of your DbSet entry to modified, but did not actually change any of the properties. so an UPDATE statement is created and executed, but to the current values.

Comment: What did you expect to be saved? That's not clear. For example, what happens in `employeeInformation.AFile.Picture.SaveAs(path)`? Describe exactly what you expected to happen. And are you sure this is not the notorious issue with localdb files getting overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new entity,you must create and add it to DbSet.

```
var entity=db.(your databasetablename).Create();
```

assign entity's properties

```
db.(your databasetablename).Add(entity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you update exist entity,you must find it from DbSet it first;

```
var entity=db.(your databasetablename).where(f=>f.Id==??).SingleOrDefault();
```

assign entity's properties

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Actually all one to many relationship data are updating but many to many relation data aren't update....i can't understand..

Comment: I do not know your db.Thus i can only give general advise.In order to update any entity(data) ,you must find it from DbSet.Beside check the error message